# Segmentation Fault (SIGSEGV) when using malloc on null pointer

Tags: c

This is what my main functions looks like. This cannot be changed as it is being used in the file my professor is using to grade the assignment.

```
char** lines = NULL;
int line_count = 5;
add_lines(&lines, line_count);
```

In this function, I need to dynamically allocate the `lines` array and store multiple strings inside. The memory is then being freed in main. This is how I am currently doing it, but I keep getting a segfault. (This function also must take a `char***`).

```
void add_lines(char*** lines, int line_count) {
    *lines = (char**)malloc(line_count*sizeof(char*));
    for (int i = 0; i < line_count; i++)
        *lines[i] = (char*)malloc(64*sizeof(char));
}
```

I am assuming this error has to do with dereferencing and trying to dynamically allocate a NULL pointer, but I'm not sure how I'd go about fixing it.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This line isn't doing what you think:

```
 *lines[i] = (char*)malloc(64*sizeof(char));
```

The array index operator `[]` has higher precedence than the unary dereference operator `*`.  So it attempts to access `lines` as an array (which it isn't), then dereference the array member.  This ends up working when `i` is 0 because it will point to the first allocated array element, but when `i` is larger you access memory past `lines` in the calling function.

You need to use parenthesis to make sure you dereference `lines` first, then index the array elements.

```
 (*lines)[i] = malloc(64*sizeof(char));
```

Also, don't cast the return value of `malloc`.  It's unnecessary and can mask subtle bugs.

Comment: @dmolz Glad I could help.  Feel free to [accept this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/help/accepted-answer) if you found it useful.